# How to implement Medium-style commenting interface in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, comments

I really like the commenting interface employed by Medium, allowing users to highlight a portion of an article and comment on that specific part.

I would like to implement a similar commenting facility in a VueJS app.

I found this package which does something similar: http://aroc.github.io/side-comments-demo/, but I want to try to find something that has been updated more recently. Also, it requires jquery, which I don't currently use and I would like to avoid adding that dependency if possible.

I would love to know if anyone has seen anything that could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a sample at https://codesandbox.io/s/medium-style-text-select-comment-box-h5o9r

Here I am adding the comments component to the root component such that it is available globally. On component `mount()` hook, I am attaching a `mouseup` method to the `window` object where any selections done are checked using

```
if (window.getSelection() && !window.getSelection().isCollapsed) {
    //execute only with the getSelection() method is available 
    //and the current selection is not collapsed
}
```

Once we do have a selection, the position on the page is calculated using the selection position and its dimensions and the floating comments component is positioned accordingly.

We can get the selected text using

```
window.getSelection().toString();
```

I would advise you to go through the sandbox as there are a lot of things going on which are not in this answer.

Comment: this is really amazing. Thanks very much! So I assume instead of "Comment", I can include a form component to save the and include the position data as well in the comment object? Then to display, just add a notification/icon in the position?

Comment: Yes you can as far as I have understood. Can you please upvote as well @user2799827

Comment: How do I display the comments near the text that they are commenting on? I see the text is retrieved in the alert I need to send the range info to the component as a prop.

Comment: I see how to get the range, but in a single document, eg I have several paragraphs. The range is calculated at each paragraph separately, so a comment on the first word of the first paragraph and another on the first word of the second par. will have the same index. How do i id the place in the doc as a whole so I can display comments appropriately on the correct line eg.?

Comment: Sorry but can you elaborate? DO you mean that what if I select multiple paragraphs at once?

Comment: I mean, I need to be able to find the exact place in the document that the comment refers to, and save the coordinates or index with the comment. That way, I can indicate to the user exactly where comments exist and also, when they click to see it, display the actual text of the comment somewhere nearby.

Comment: You can have unique IDs for each paragraph and associate your comments with it. Not sure what is stopping you. You can easily get the attributes of the selected element.

Comment: I created a new question. : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61149760/trying-to-display-comments-near-appropriate-doc-range-in-vue-component. Would you mind adding your easy solution there?